Migration from Artifactory to GCP artifact registry
I want to migrate our huge maven artifacts repository to the artifact registry on Google's cloud platform.
The process seems is long, and manual upload of each artifact to the maven repo on GCP is tedious and will take an unpractical amount of time. Keep in mind there is a massive amount of artifacts to be migrated.
I wanted to know if there are any already-existing tools for such a task since this doesn't seem out of the ordinary. Even if there are no tools, perhaps an already existing course of action to complete this task.
Automating this myself seemed difficult, because of my limited scripting knowledge with BASH and a general unfamiliarity with JFrog's artifactory tools.
Eventually I considered executing a recursive copy of the artifacts to GCS but I fear this would remove some of the functionality like the attached pom.xml files to most of the artifacts

Can you please have a look at the similar issue at the cloud community which might help you to resolve the issue.
